# using inheritence for data type purposes in JPA

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, jpa, orm

I have some Entities that look like this:

```
@Entity
public abstract class AbstractEntity{

    @Id
    private Long id;
    String name;
    User author;
    @Lob
    byte[] data;

}


public class EntityOne extends AbstractEntity{
    // nothing new
}


public class EntityTwo extends AbstractEntity{
    // nothing new
}


public class EntityThree extends AbstractEntity{
    // nothing new
}
```

The `byte[]` defined in the superclass is the interesting part of each subclass entity. The reason I want to subclass is to enforce typing rules, as some parts of the program require `EntityThree`, while some parts of the program require `EntityTwo`. the `byte[]` will have completely different meaning from subclass to subclass.

It feels a little strange, because I don't expect that any of the subclasses will add any fields or methods... So i use inheritance only as a typing tool.

Is this a reasonable design? A better way to accomplish this? Does it break any best practices?

Comment: If you don't have anything specific in the subclasses then why are subclassing?

Comment: because the differences are apparent in the byte[] only. And I still want to be able to do things like instanceOf to verify that I have the correct subclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good OO practice. For the database, use the SINGLE_TABLE Inheritance strategy (the default), and maybe use a custom @DiscriminatorValue per subclass, otherwise you'll get classnames in your table.

From a DBA perspective, there is no difference between this and using a single class with a property TYPE.

For OO, the subclasses can be much more usefull, e.g. you can use it to implement certain methods differently or implement the visitor or strategy pattern instead of tedious if-then-else or instanceof structures.

Comment: yes, I just read what the visitor pattern is, and it is precisely what Im going for here. Thanks for reassuring me.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing the exact use-case, but it looks like you just want to reuse the common fields in all the entities, but that no other entity will have references to AbstractEntity - only to one specific subclass. In this case, you should map the superclass with @MappedSuperclass rather than with @Entity. Each entity will have its own table, and can override the mapping defined in the mapped superclass.

Note that if I'm mistaken, and you really need an entity inheritance, using `instanceof`, at least with Hibernate, will cause problems, because you might have a proxy to the base class, which doesn't know yet the exact subclass the foreign key is pointing to, and which is thus not an instance of any of the subclasses.